# Moving files sorted by Date from internal storage to SD

Tags: android, bash, shell, file, tasker

I would like to ask you some help to build the right Job to do the following steps:
Starting everyday at 4:45 AM, get files from pathX and move it to pathY with these rules:

- files modified date must be 1 week older from now
- files size must be at least over 1MB
- files extension must be .mp4 or .mp3

By using the shell commands, a possible solution would be:

```
source=/path/to/X
dest=path/to/Y
find $source -name '*.mp[34]' -size +1M -mtime +7 -exec mv {} $dest \;
```

I tried it now on my phone (which is not rooted) using Tasker v.5.9.2, and this is the result:

```
00.29.47/E Run Shell: ->
00.29.47/E Run Shell: ->
00.29.47/E Run Shell: ->
00.29.47/Shell runBackground source="/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video"
dest="/storage/A232-BF34/Media/WhatsApp Video"
find $source -name '*.mp[34]' -size +1M -mtime +1 -exec mv {} $dest \; root: false timeout: -1
00.29.47/Shell start process-thread ID 110080
00.29.47/E add wait type Shell1 time 2147483647
00.29.47/E add wait type Shell1 done
00.29.47/E add wait task
00.29.47/E Error: 1
```

I tried to store the `stderr` from `find` command but "out.txt" file has not been created. Here is the find command i launched:

```
find $source -name '*.mp[34]' -size +7 -mtime +7 -exec mv {} $dest \; 2>$dest/out.txt
```

From the error above, I see this error:

```
root: false timeout: -1
```

but I don't know how much is useful for understanding the error.

So, I really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is **totally correct**. But since **your phone is not rooted**, the **exec command** is returning an error.
Although, I have found one solution/workaround for non-root users :

> Images/Videos speak Better than words. Check Images below for clarity. Images are attached as links.

---

## SOLUTION:

- `find $source -name '*.mp[34]' -size +7 -mtime +7`

[Find command reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N23GB.jpg)

Run above command **without exec**, **Store Output/Error** in two different variable. This **variable will contain all the file paths** that has satisfied all the conditions mentioned in find command.

- Use `Variable Search Replace action` on Output variable to replace `\n` with `,`

[Search Replace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sptE.jpg)

- Next, Use `Variable Split action` to split each file path into separate variable with separator as `,`. Ex : %Output0 %Output1 ..

[Variable Split Action Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chK0k.jpg)

- Use `for Loop` to iterate over these values and apply `Move action`.

[For loop Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0USoS.jpg)

[Copy Action Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SZAN.jpg)

[List of Tasks to use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAAQg.jpg)

**After Applying these Tasks/Actions, we will fulfil requirement without root access.**

Hence , This will move your files from internal storage to sd card as per your conditions without root access.

---

### **I have read, analysed, tried this process on my rooted phone but without letting root access to tasker actions. I have learned some things i want to share with you, if interested read further.**

### Why root access is important

If your phone had root access, then this one line command `find $source -name '*.mp[34]' -size +1M -mtime +7 -exec mv {} $dest \;` would do all the job. But without root access, We had two options left.

---

**1st option**

- `find $source -name '*.mp[34]' -size +1M -mtime +7 | xargs mv --target-directory=$dest`

The **above command works perfectly in linux bash shell** **but** in **tasker shell**, we have one small **problem** i.e **mv command does not have --target-directory option** which exclusively tells mv command that destination directory is = $dest instead of interpreting second argument as destination which raises an error and **this method fails in tasker**.

Again Better than words. Check Image Link below

[Move command option limitations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqR68.jpg)

[Raises error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROS8R.jpg)

---

**2nd Option that works but little long**

**Mentioned at the start of post.**

---